# I need to change port number on apache http server

Tags: apache, http

Instructions

1 
Log on to your Apache server computer with an administrator account.

2 
Open the Start menu and click on the "My Computer" icon.

3 
Navigate to the C:\wamp\Apache2\conf directory on your server's main hard drive or the drive where WAMP has been previously installed.

4 
Find the file labeled "http.conf" and double-click on it to open it in the Windows Notepad application.

5 
Press the "control" and "F" keys at the same time to launch the search utility.

6 
Type "80" into the search field and hit "Find Next." You will now be taken to the part of the configuration file where the localhost port is set.

7 
Change "80" to the port of your choice and then save the "http.conf" file to update your server. You may need to restart your server in order for the new port to be recognized.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question or are you just sharing your thoughts?

Comment: If you want to share your thought, then ask a question, and answer it your self. If a real question, ask a question, then say this is what I have tried/think-will-work-but-am-scared-to-try, then include what you already have.

Answer (score 4):

The item you're searching for in the configuration file is "Listen". Default value is 80, which is standard for HTTP.

Example:

```
Listen 8000
```

reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

Answer (score 3):

Simple and Quick.
Open Apache configuration file "httpd.conf"
by default it runs on 80 port. so you can change it to any value.
Here i am changing  80 to 81.

---

eg.
"Listen 80"   to "Listen 81"
Now re-start the apache web server.
Thats it.
you are done with it.
Thanx.